# Proper use of shared vars in Visual Basic.NET

Tags: vb.net, oop

```
Class klass

   Private Shared state As Boolean


   Public Sub savestate (ByVal value As Boolean)
       state = value
   End Sub

   Public Function getstate () As Boolean
      Return state 
   End Function

   Private Sub work()
      savestatet(false)
   End Sub 

   Private Sub work2()
     If getstate()
       ....

   End Sub
 ...
End Class
```

Is it correct to use shared variables in this way or just accessing them like `state = false, and if state... do something`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this is done using a property for clearer syntax, but, per se, it is not wrong using a couple of get/set functions.

```
Private Shared internalState As Boolean

Public Property State() As Boolean
    Get
      Return internalState
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
      internalState = value
    End Set
End Property
```

But keep in mind that a Shared variable is 'shared' between every instance of the class. So if you declare

```
Dim c1 = new klass()
c1.State = True

Dim c2 = new klass()
Console.WriteLine(c2.ToString)  ' Prints True'
```

I want also to add that using a property is a way better in terms of usability when you have an IDE that could suggest you the members of a class with an Intellisense feature. You have only one item (the property name) to search for and not two names of methods, related but scattered alphabetically. (getstate, savestate)

Answer (score 0):

> Is correct to use the shared variables this way?

Normally, you'd do this via a [Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bc3dtbky.aspx), not a pair of methods.  Internally, a property is just two methods (a getter and setter method for getting and setting the value, plus any extra logic required), but it "looks like" the variable itself, which simplifies usage.